# Xcode 4.2 and Three20 wont compile armv6

Tags: xcode, three20, armv7, armv6

I have an application running perfectly in the simulators in Xcode 4.2

To build and Archive to publish to the appstore I receive an error indicating I need to include a armv6 build. Forums suggest to clear the build-targets and include "armv6 armv7" which I did. With Ios Deployment target of iOS 3.0

When I hook up my test-iPod and start an archive operation (RELEASE build) I receive the following error:

> Ignoring file /xxx/Release-iphoneos/libThree20UICommon.a, file was
>   built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
>   (repeat over all Three20 libraries)
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTTableViewDataSource", referenced from: Objc-class-ref
>   in ContactsDataSource.o

I have tried changing "Build Active Architecture Only", which works but doesn't include the armv6 for the appstore.

Has someone encountered and solved this problem ?

Thanks!
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found that going through and setting the 'Architectures' (not 'Valid Arch') to 'armv6 armv7' fixed the problem for me. Tedious, as you have to do it to each of the subprojects in Three20's dependencies folders, but success.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution changing the Three20.bundle file in resources and not just the project files of Three20.

Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No" and life is bright again.

Comment: hm, unfortunately it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I dont have my mac right now, but i think that you also need to include the armv6 in the plist.

Comment: This hasn't solved my problem: I've tried to add "armv6 armv7" in the target builds, changing compilers, ... to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the Project format from Xcode 3.1 to Xcode 3.2 - leaving Build Active Arch Only as "No"